# How to extract the corresponding key whose value contains the item from a list?

Tags: python

I have a list and a dictionary. For each item in the list, i want to retrieve the key in the dictionary whose value contains that item.

I tried writing the code that takes an item from the list and loops through the dictionary each time to see if the value contains that item and return the key. I think this would be O(n2) complexity.

```
my_list = ['1.1.1.1','2.2.2.2','3.3.3.3']
my_dict = {
            1234 : '4.4.4.4,5.5.5.5,2.2.2.2',
            4567 : '6.6.6.6,7.7.7.7,1.1.1.1',
            8910 : '8.8.8.8,9.9.9.9,3.3.3.3'
            }

def get_key(my_list, my_dict):

    for item in my_list:
        for key, value in my_dict.items():
            temp_list = []
            temp_list = value.split(',')
            if item in temp_list:
                print(key)

get_key(my_list, my_dict)

Output:
4567
1234
8910
```

For the item 2.2.2.2, the key 1234 should be returned and so on.

Is there a more optimized way to achieve this?

Comment: @Tom Karzes- sorry about that. Edit my question now.

Comment: Please provide more information. Are the values unique? Is your data actually large enough for scalability to be noticeable?

Comment: The fastest way to do this is to create an inverse dict, i.e. one whose keys are `'4.4.4.4'`, `'5.5.5.5'`, etc.  The inner loop of what you showed above can be adapted to do this.  Then, after creating the dict, you can have a single loop that iterates over `my_list` and simply looks up the desired keys.  So instead of a pair of nested loops, you would have a pair of sequential, non-nested loops.  If `my_list` has 100 elements, then the new version would run roughly 100 times faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are looking for exact matches, you can invert the dictionary to search through. Conversion is O(n) once, but lookup is O(1) afterwards.

```
inverse = {
    value: key
    for key, values in my_dict.items()
    for value in values.split(',')
}
```

Given this inverted structure, you can directly look up the keys from your list:

```
for item in my_list:
    print(inverse[item])
```

Both the inversion and lookup for all items is O(n). Since the loops are not nested, the total complexity stays at O(n) total.

Comment: Nice solution.  This is what I was proposing in my comment.  Nice dict comprehension too.

Comment: Thanks @MisterMiyagi

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
my_list = ['1.1.1.1','2.2.2.2','3.3.3.3']
my_dict = {
        1234 : '4.4.4.4,5.5.5.5,2.2.2.2',
        4567 : '6.6.6.6,7.7.7.7,1.1.1.1',
        8910 : '8.8.8.8,9.9.9.9,3.3.3.3'
        }
result = []
for i in my_dict:
    s = list(set(my_dict.get(i).split(',')).intersection(my_list))
    result.insert(my_list.index(s[0]),i)
print(result)
```

you will get the output like this

```
[4567, 1234, 8910]
```

Comment: please accept the answer so that it can be helpful for others

Comment: This isn't what OP requested.  OP wants a sequence of keys whose order corresponds to the order in `my_list`.  Look at the sample output in the post.  It's also very slow, since it again uses a doubly-nested loop (the inner loop is in the call to `intersection`).  Doesn't help OP.

Comment: if you want in the same context then just print 'result' in loop you will get the result in the same context

Comment: How does this help?  OP was looking for a solution with better time complexity.  This solution is O(n**2), which is no better than OP's.  The problem has an O(n) solution, which is what OP wants.

Comment: here we are using one 'for' loop so its complexity is O(n) and you the result in a list. that is the output

Comment: and if we want the same output in same context that question demands then we apply the second loop outside the first loop in result then the complexity becomes O(2n)  that is O(n)

Comment: This does not work when a dict value matches multiple elements in the list, it does not have the correct ordering once my_list becomes large and is not sorted, and worst of all it is still O(n**2). The for loop is O(n), and the nested list operations (intersection and index) are O(n) as well.

Comment: @shubham No, as I already explained, the call to `intersection` is O(n), so the code you posted is O(n**2).  Just because the code is in a function doesn't make it constant-time.  Similarly, if you call the `sort()` method of a Python list, it's O(n\*log(n)), not constant-time as you seem to believe.  There are *two* loops in your algorithm:  The explicit loop, whose trip count is the number of dict elements, and the inner loop, whose trip count is the number of elements of `my_list`.

Comment: ok @TomKarzes i understand what you want to say, but in this problem we cannot find the complexity less than O(n**2)

Comment: @shubham An O(n) solution is utterly trivial.  I posted a description of it hours ago in a comment on OP's post.  It consists of two serial loops.  The first loop constructs a temporary dict in O(n) time.  The second produces the result, also in O(n) time.  Total time:  O(n).

Comment: Thanks Shubham, @Tom Karzes for the knowledge shared in the comments.